# control height and remove spaces between rotated divs

Tags: html, css

I am creating a floating menu with a couple of links, I applied a css to rotate vertically (-90deg)
but the height is more than desired, how can I decrease it? and I want to remove the spaces between each link too please.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6N5/)

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
margin-top:0px;
font-size: 14px;
width:96px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
height: 98%;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

negative margins and hard-coding the heights solved the problem!

```
#menu
{height:100px;}

#menu > a {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
font-size: 100%;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
height: 40px;
position:relative;
margin-left:-30px;
margin-right:-30px;
bottom:-30px;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6N5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use media queries to achieve this. You can find a quick example below. Simply set the desired resolution that you want the change to happen at and define the classes and styles you want to be affected.

### Additional Resources

Here's an awesome link on media queries to get you started:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

If you're interested in learning more about responsive this book won't disappoint. Super quick read and it'll answer all of your questions on responsive:

http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

### JSFiddle & Sample Code

http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6N5/2/

CSS

```
@media all and (max-width : 800px) {
    #menu > a{
        width: 50px;
        font-size:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MarioD, the problem is not in achieving a responsive design, I am trying to decrease the "horizontal heights" (widths) of the rotated #menu>a

Answer (score 0):

you need to set explicite `width` and `height` to `<a>` , wrap text inside another container that you rotate and translate back down.

To get rid of space in betwwen `inline-block` element, you can set `font-size:0;` at #menu, since you set font-size: `<a>` , font-size will reduce your `white-space` within HTML code to nothing visible.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6N5/1/)**

```
#menu > a {
    overflow:visible;
    margin-top:0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#menu>a>span, #menu>a {
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    min-width:60px;
}
#menu>a>span {
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-right:-5em;/* remove this if you do not want see span overflow; */
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px black;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translatex(-60px);
    transform-origin: top left;
    background: rgba(153, 153, 153, .8);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

and links are formed like this `<a href="#"><span>Item</span></a>`.

Comment: Thank you, but in the demo you provided, text is not rotated 90degrees, could you check that please? thanks

Comment: @iJassar i did not add prefix , cause in FF they are not needed anymore. add them or use a script to add them automaticly.like i did here :  http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6N5/4/

Comment: text is not rotated in the fiddle example you provided... I did exactly what you said in my website and it isn't working either. could it be because I'm using chrome? thank you.

Comment: it worked now...negative margins and hard-coding the heights solved the problem!....

    `#menu
    {height:100px;}
   
    #menu > a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 font-size: 100%;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 height: 40px;
 position:relative;
 margin-left:-30px;
 margin-right:-30px;
 bottom:-30px;}`
....
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV6N5/5/)

Comment: translate(-xxpx) + transform-origin  was meant to master, control position at screen of rotated box, did you not use it as in the exemple ?

Comment: I did use it but it didn't work, thanks again anyway =D

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you rotate your items, your "height" is actually your *width* declaration.

Unfortunately, from the way you've architected your heights/widths using percentages, you cannot really achieve what you want, as there is now way to tell a child element to be a certain percent of it's *parent's height*, which is what you're aiming for (`a`'s width should be 100% of the `#menu`'s height).

If you want, there's still some things you could do:

1. If you're calculating your measurements within a range and you know only a little bit will ever overhang, you can give `#menu {overflow:hidden;}` to hide the children's excess. This is more of a simple hack, than a real fix.
2. You can hardcode the height of menu, and give that same height to the *width* of your children. (If you additionally want padding, you can subtract hardcoded values, or change our `box-sizing` to a `border-box` depending on your accessibility reqs).
3. To better facilitate #2, you could use `rem` to hardcode your widths/heights as a different responsive practice as opposed to percentages

Really, all you need to do is ensure that the widths of your children are the same as the height of your menu, however you want to tackle that is up to you, but fluid percentages aren't going to work well.

Comment: the "vertical width" is not the problem, I've already set it to 96px, my problem is in the "horizontal heights", even when I set them to hardcoded heights, or auto, I still have a space between <a>'s